# React как собрать данные с формы и отрендерить по запросу

Tags: reactjs

Нужна помощь. Не могу понять как получить данные с checkbox и потом по запросу пользователя отфильтровать. И вывести услуги.
Подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении двигаться?
Данные для карточек получаю с json использую map и вывожу.
Подскажите как собрать данные с формы. Буду очень благодарен.
Подскажите путь.
Может у кого пример есть я разберусь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пример кода, а не то, как это выглядит на сайте

Comment: Привести пример кода не могу. Может подскажите как собрать данные с checkbox

Comment: мне нужно по нажатии кнопки собрать все данные в массив.

Comment: я добавил код компонента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В React есть несколько способов "собирать" данные с формы.

1 использовать состояния https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

2 использовать ссылки https://learn-reactjs.ru/core/refs-and-the-dom

Ничего нового придумывать не нужно, да это и не имеет смысла.

```js
const items = ["100","200","300","400","500"]
class SomeApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.formref = React.createRef();
    this.onClickSubmit = this.onClickSubmit.bind(this);
}
  onClickSubmit(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    for(let key of this.formref.current.elements){
      alert(key.checked+key.name)
    }    
    
  }
  render() {
    return (
            <form ref={this.formref} onSubmit={this.onClickSubmit}>
              {items.map((value, key)=>{
        return(
        <div><input type="checkbox" name={"ch"+key}/>{value}</div>
        )
        })}
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
            </form>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SomeApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Вот так можно сделать через ref, если не использовать state, который использовать в вашем случае не имеет смысла, потому что вы ждете нажатия кнопки.

Comment: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html тут еще более подробно

Comment: В теории все понятно но на практики не хватает опыта.

Comment: Может есть пример?

Comment: @user395686 добавил пример, он является чисто синтетическим, поэтому перед тем, как использовать его, нужно доработать для ваших нужд. С другой стороны не использование стейта снижает нагрузку приложения на браузер, учитывая, что вы ждете нажатия кнопки

Comment: @user395686 пожалуйста удалите свой ответ ниже(который является дополнением вопроса) я уже поправил ваш вопрос

Comment: Большое спасибо) Буду пробывать